# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+y^2)^2}dy$

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I'm tryng calculate thins integral by residue methods $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+y^2)^2}dy$$

I think the roots is $\frac{1}{(y+i)^2(y-i)^2}$, with his poles are $(y-i)^2$, so the results by sum of residue is given $2\pi$, but it is not beating with the feedback it is $\pi/2$. Someone can help me?

Comment: dy or dx ? >Because your integral dosent depend on x

Comment: @Isham I cannot make the OP's question any clearer than you can.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are relatively new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say [in what context](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) you encountered the problem, and what you've tried; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help us better understand what you are having difficulty with. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", "Help" etc.) to be rude when asking for help.

Comment: Btw, are you sure about getting $(y+1)^2(y-1)^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: I'm sorry for dx integrand, I scribe wrong, thank you for tell me. I just note another my mistake, just wrong digitation. -.-'
About the Denominator, I don't have sure, but it's kind of obvious that $(1+y^2)^2$=$(1+y^2)(1+y^2)$={roots of both}->$(y+i)(y-i).(y+i)(y-i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the semicircle $\Gamma=[-R,R] \cup \{z:|z|=R, \mathrm{Im}z>0\}$. The integral on this path is

$$I=\oint_\Gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(1+z^2)^2}=\int_{-R}^R\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}\mathrm{d}t +\int_0^\pi\frac{Rie^{i\theta}}{(1+Re^{2i\theta})^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Let us call the second term $I_2$ and notice
$$ |I_2|\leq\int_0^\pi\frac{R}{|1+Re^{2i\theta}|^2}\mathrm{d}\theta\rightarrow0$$

as $R\rightarrow \infty$. This implies $$ \lim\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty} I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}\mathrm{d}t$$ On the other hand by the residue theorem

$$ I=2\pi i\mathrm{Res}\left( \frac{1}{(1+z^2)^2}, z=i\right)=2\pi i \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}\right]_{z=i}=2\pi i \frac{-2}{(2i)^3}=2\pi i \frac{1}{4i}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Because $z=i$ is the only singularity in the semicircle, the other singularity in $z=-i$ is on the other half of the plane! Do you understand the reasoning?

To the other answerers: what's wrong in using a powerful method instead of a long and tedious one? And the question specifically asked for a residue method solution, which implies that this is probably what OP wants to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the integrand is $\dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$, I don't think we need complex analysis methods here.

Noting that the integrand is even and then applying the substitution $x\mapsto\tan(y)$ makes the integral,

$$2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\cos^4(y)\sec^2(y)\,\mathrm dy=2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2(y)\,\mathrm dy$$

Can you take it from here?

---

In case you need to solve it using residue methods, note that the poles are $x=\pm i$ (both of order $2$)

Comment: Usually these sorts of problems are given with the intent that they are to be solved using the tools of complex analysis (and in particular residue-calculus, as indicated by the tags).

Comment: But the problem that I'm solving, ask for both methods, either complex and non-complex solutions. I solve by a non-complex methods, but I have a little troube to solving by using residues.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I agree with Prasun that complex analysis isn't really necessary.

Starting from the indefinite integral

$$\int {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)}^2}}}dx}$$

Let
$$x = \tan \left( u \right)$$

Then
$$\frac{{dx}}{{du}} = {\sec ^2}u = \frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u}}$$

so 
$$dx = \frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u}}$$

$$\int {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)}^2}}}dx}  = \int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {1 + {{\tan }^2}u} \right)}^2}}}} du$$

Since ${\tan ^2}u =  - 1 + {\sec ^2}u$:
$$\int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {1 + {{\tan }^2}u} \right)}^2}}}du}  = \int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {1 - 1 + {{\sec }^2}u} \right)}^2}}}du} $$

$$\int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {1 + {{\tan }^2}u} \right)}^2}}}du}  = \int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {{{\sec }^2}u} \right)}^2}}}du}$$

$$\int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u{{\left( {{{\sec }^4}u} \right)}^2}}}du}  = \int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u \cdot {{\sec }^4}u}}du}$$

Since $\frac{1}{{{{\sec }^4}u}} = {\cos ^4}u$:
$$\int {\frac{1}{{{{\cos }^2}u{{\sec }^4}u}}du}  = \int {\frac{{{{\cos }^4}u}}{{{{\cos }^2}u}}du}  = \int {{{\cos }^2}\left( u \right)du} $$

And like said, since the integrand is even:
$$\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)}^2}}}dx}  = 2\int_0^{\infty /2} {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 + {x^2}} \right)}^2}}}dx = } 2\int_0^{\infty /2} {{{\cos }^2}\left( u \right)du} $$

Try and take it from there.. if get stuck or don't know how to proceed, I'd be glad to help you further.

One hint... 
since $$x = tan(u)$$
... that means that 
$$u = \arctan x$$

You'll end up needing that.